# How to get all days name of week in arabic format WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf

I would like to get all days of the week in arabic and english format , I have a solution for the english format but I need the arabic format ,

```
   DayOfWeek[] days = {
        DayOfWeek.Sunday,
        DayOfWeek.Monday,
        DayOfWeek.Tuesday,
        DayOfWeek.Wednesday,
        DayOfWeek.Thursday,
        DayOfWeek.Friday,
        DayOfWeek.Saturday };

        daygrd.ItemsSource = days;
```

this shows the days in the english format :

- Monday
- Tuesday
- ...

What I need exactly is get the days like this :

- الاثنين
- الثلاثاء
- الاربعاء
- ...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this

```cs
    string[] days_in_arabic= new CultureInfo("ar-BH").DateTimeFormat.DayNames;
    foreach(var d in days_in_arabic)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(d);
    }
```

Comment: Why you edit your solution ??? the fisrt solution was worked for me and gives me the days that I need them , I mean this line : `string[] days_in_arabic= new CultureInfo("ar-BH").DateTimeFormat.DayNames;`

Answer (score 1):

You can try CultureInfo:

```
CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("ar-BH").DateTimeFormat.DayNames; //For Bahrain culture
```

Comment: Can you please explain the code ? because it give me an error .

Comment: You need to add namespace System.Globalization, either by `using System.Globalization` or `System.Globalization.CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("ar-BH").DateTimeFormat.DayNames`

Comment: @dontbyteme that's correct. I've ommited the using part to be more concise. Also  Visual Studio IDE will suggest you a an automatic code fix which adds the neccessary usings if you hover your mouse over the error.

Comment: @AndrewMalachov no the error is not related to a missed namespace, is something else . I will update the question , but fortunately, The solution of Krishna Muppalla worked for me.

Comment: @abdou_dev could you please describe what is not working. Please add an exception message, a stack trace, a compiler error message. Everything works great in my case. here are results from C# interactive tool window in VS. 
The code: `System.Globalization.CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("ar-BH").DateTimeFormat.DayNames`.
The result: `string[7] { "الأحد", "الإثنين", "الثلاثاء", "الأربعاء", "الخميس", "الجمعة", "السبت" }`

Comment: `Error CS0201 Only assignment, call, increment, decrement, await, and new object expressions can be used as a statement`

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `CultureInfo` class to display English strings to different formats like Chinese, Japanese, Arabic etc.

For that import Globalization namespace in your project and use the following code to get day names in Arabic format.

```
using System.Globalization;
System.Globalization.CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("ar-E").DateTimeFormat.DayNames;
```